# Opening VS2012 project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

my company only has VS2010, but I need to work on a project that was created in VS2012, is there a way I can work on the project without buying VS2012?

Answer (score 1):

You can use VS2010 and VS2012 on same project. In my company some developers use one, some another. No problems so far...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what kind of project it is but you may want to try - 
[VS Express - and it is free](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)